Is it permissible for foreigners to seek crowdfunding in China under the regulations set by the Chinese government?
Does the Chinese government permit foreigners to launch crowdfunding campaigns within the country, or are there regulatory barriers that effectively limit such activities to Chinese citizens or companies?
Given the Chinese government's tight regulatory control over financial activities, I would like to understand if there are specific policies that prohibit or restrict foreign nationals from accessing crowdfunding as a means of raising funds. Are there any notable political or regulatory concerns that influence the ability of foreigners to participate in crowdfunding in China?

Interesting Q. I suppose though the PRC government is mostly look for foreign investors that bring their own funds.

Probably better suited for "Law", or perhaps "Expatriates".   If you are based in China, then you certainly need to follow Chinese Law. Which makes this mostly a matter for Expariates.

What do you mean by foreigners? Those living in China (with some status or other), those from overseas, those with businesses or other links?
